# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \sqrt {4x^2-x} +2x$

Tags: limits

Rationalising gives
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4x^2 -x} -2x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt {4-\frac 1x}-2}$$
$$=-\infty$$

But the correct ans is $\frac 14$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553757/finding-the-limit-of-sqrt4x2x72x/3553777#3553777  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520666/calculating-lim-x-to-infty-fracx-sqrtx21/3520673#3520673 OR   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513030/trouble-finding-limits-at-infty/3513130#3513130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x \lt 0$ you have $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ and not $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ as the square root is by definition non negative.

Comment: That’s interesting.......and very frustrating